# How to prevent relative layout from collapsing

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

### Hello, I am currently making a settings menu defined with relative layout

[image]

### Unfortunately, it collapses when the thing is too small. Is there a way where I can prevent this from happening? What is best practice to fix this? Minimum width? Wrapping?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/outline"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Show my picture"
        android:textColor="#7E57C2"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @nabillondon Basically I have 2 questions. 1) Does this matter? 2) If it matters, I would like to somehow specify that RelativeLayout have a minimum width such that both textView & switch do not obstruct each other (e.g. it shrinks until left edge of switch touches right edge of textview - then it stops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/switch1"
        android:text="Show my picture"
        android:textColor="#7E57C2"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The only change is that, the switch is fixed and aligned to parent right and the textview is set to left of the switch. If display is too small, textview will adjust and will not overlap with the switch. Key thing here is

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/switch1"
```